# How do i change the size of my drawing using a button (java)?

Tags: java, swing, button, drawing

I'm drawing flowers and I need the 'head' to double in size when I press the 'fertilize' button and then to reset to their original size when I press the 'reset size' button. I'm using Netbeans. Nothing I've tried so far has worked sooo....help? :)

[image]

Code for Panel:

```
package Versie4;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class PanelFlowers extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    private int amount, size;
    private String color = "";

    public PanelFlowers() {
        initComponents();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        int teller;

        g.setColor(Color.RED);  //flowerpot
        g.fillRect(300, 350, 500, 100);

        int x = 1;
        int size = 40;
        for (teller=1; teller <= amount ;teller++) { 

            //Flower 1
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);  //stem
        g.fillRect(320 + x, 250, 10, 100);


            switch (color) {            //Colours of petals
                case "red":
                    g.setColor(Color.red);
                    break;
                case "blue":
                    g.setColor(Color.blue);
                    break;
                case "yellow":
                    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
                    break;
                case "orange":
                    g.setColor(Color.orange);
                    break;
                case "pink":
                    g.setColor(Color.PINK);
                    break;
                case "purple":
                    g.setColor(new Color(102, 0, 204));
                    break;
            }

        g.fillOval(304 + x, 190, size, size); //petals
        g.fillOval(330 + x, 210, size, size);
        g.fillOval(320 + x, 240, size, size);
        g.fillOval(290 + x, 240, size, size);
        g.fillOval(280 + x, 210, size, size);


        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);  //pistil
        g.fillOval(312 + x, 225, 25, 25);

        x = teller * 80;

        }



    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        lblamount = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtamount = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        lblcolor = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtcolor = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        btngrow = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnreset = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnfertilize = new javax.swing.JButton();

        lblamount.setText("Amount: ");

        txtamount.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txtamountActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        lblcolor.setText("Color: ");

        txtcolor.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txtcolorActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btngrow.setText("Grow!");
        btngrow.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btngrowActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnreset.setText("Reset Size");

        btnfertilize.setText("Fertilize");
        btnfertilize.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnfertilizeActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(lblamount)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(txtamount, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 57, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(41, 41, 41)
                .addComponent(lblcolor)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(txtcolor, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 59, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(btngrow)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(btnfertilize)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(btnreset)
                .addContainerGap(185, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(lblamount)
                    .addComponent(txtamount, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(lblcolor)
                    .addComponent(txtcolor, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btngrow)
                    .addComponent(btnreset)
                    .addComponent(btnfertilize))
                .addContainerGap(412, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void txtamountActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    }                                         

    private void txtcolorActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void btngrowActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    amount = Integer.parseInt(txtamount.getText());
    color = this.txtcolor.getText();
    repaint();

    }                                       

    private void btnfertilizeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
       size = size * 2;
    }                                            

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnfertilize;
    private javax.swing.JButton btngrow;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnreset;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblamount;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblcolor;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtamount;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtcolor;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Code for Frame:

```
package Versie4;


public class FrameFlowers extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public FrameFlowers() {
        initComponents();
        setSize(900, 600);
        setContentPane(new PanelFlowers());
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FrameFlowers.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FrameFlowers.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FrameFlowers.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FrameFlowers.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new FrameFlowers().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: [crossposted](http://www.coderanch.com/t/624295/GUI/java/change-size-drawing-button)

Answer (score 2):

I will give you some hints this time. You can do it your self.

1. When you are drawing the Oval, you are using a parameter `size`, which is an `int`. Change the value of this `size` variable to zoom-in and zoom-out.
2. Calculate every other size in terms of this `size` variable: like size of the oval of `pistil`

   ```
   g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);  //pistil
   g.fillOval(312 + x, 225, size/2, size/2); // <---- removing fixed value 25
   ```
3. Now, try to change the shift variable `x` in terms of the `size`:

   ```
   x = teller * (size * 2);
   ```

**Edit:** Now, I have done a resolution for you, as it will take too much words to explain in speech. Please bear in mind that a real living object(like a bunny, or a flower) is not possible to achieve in any simple way using Geometry. However for zooming in: i actually meant the same thing you want; growing flower when we fertilize. I gave you hints so that you would be able to find out that how much complex it is.

```
@Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        int teller;

        g.setColor(Color.RED);  //flowerpot 
        g.fillRect(300, 400, 500, 100);

        int x = 1;
       // int size = 40;
        for (teller=1; teller <= amount ;teller++) { 

            //Flower 1
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);  //stem
        g.fillRect(320 + x + size/4, 250 - size*2, size/4, 400 - (250 - size*2));


        g.setColor(new Color(102, 0, 204)); //<<---- using purple, removed switch-ase

        int centerX = 320 + x ;
        int centerY = 250 - size*2 ;

        g.fillOval(centerX - size/2 , centerY - size/4, size, size); //petals
        g.fillOval(centerX + size/2 , centerY - size/4, size, size);
        g.fillOval(centerX - size/4 , centerY + size/4, size, size);
        g.fillOval(centerX + size/4 , centerY + size/4, size, size);
       g.fillOval(centerX ,  centerY - size/2, size, size);


        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);  //pistil
        g.fillOval(centerX + size/4 , centerY , size/2, size/2);

        x = teller * size * 3;

        }

    }
```

---

**Edit:** Don't forget to call `repaint()` in the `btnfertilizeActionPerformed(ActionEvent)` method.

```
private void btnfertilizeActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){                                           
           size = size * 2;
           repaint();
 }
```

You will see that it is still not so perfect because of the fractional error resulted from *division*.

Comment: ok I did step 2 and 3 but I'm not entirely sure what you mean with "Change the value of this size variable to zoom-in and zoom-out.".
if I understand correctly, this method will zoom everything but everything like the pistil ect. will be made smaller?

Comment: That just messes up my loop?
Isn't there a way I can just multiply the size of my petals by 2? Zooming EVERYTHING seems a bit like overkill...

Comment: yup,  it kinda messes up things. yes :). There are lots of calculation you will need yes. That is why it is always hard to draw living object using geometry. check my edit. I have done a little snippets for you

Comment: When I try that solution nothing happens. I'm sorry, I'm totally lost. None of this makes sense to me :(

Comment: Nicole, don't be sorry. Come down. I am not going anywhere. have you called `repaint()` in the `btnfertilizeActionPerformed` function ? Just replace your `paintComponent` function with the one i have given. Then you should have a output. See my last edit.

Comment: Yes I did all of that and when I press grow or fertilize nothing happens.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41815/discussion-between-sage-and-nicole)

Comment: @Nicole, I have seen that you left a message in the chat box. You are incredible for being an artist. I am an artist too ;). However, Were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: Thanks :)
I did. Probably not ideal but I'm happy with the result. Should I post it here?

Comment: If it is not ideal, it is still OK. In programming we expect the efficient output and that matters ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for anyone interested:

```
package Versie4;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class PanelFlowers extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    private int amount, petalSize = 40, pistilSize = 25, pistilPositionX = 312, 
            pistilPositionY = 225, stemPositionX = 320,stemPositionY = 250;
    private String color = "";
    private boolean fertilized = false;
    public PanelFlowers() {
        initComponents();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        setBackground(Color.CYAN);





        g.setColor(Color.RED);  //flowerpot
        g.fillRect(300, 350, 500, 100);


        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        // cloud        
       g.fillPolygon(cloud);



        int teller;
        int x = 1;
        for (teller=1; teller <= amount ;teller++) { 

            //Flower 1
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);  //stem
        g.fillRect(stemPositionX + x, stemPositionY, 10, 100);


            switch (color) {            //Colours of petals
                case "red":
                    g.setColor(Color.red);
                    break;
                case "blue":
                    g.setColor(Color.blue);
                    break;
                case "yellow":
                    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
                    break;
                case "orange":
                    g.setColor(Color.orange);
                    break;
                case "pink":
                    g.setColor(Color.PINK);
                    break;
                case "purple":
                    g.setColor(new Color(102, 0, 204));
                    break;
            }

        g.fillOval(304 + x, 190, petalSize, petalSize); //petals
        g.fillOval(330 + x, 210, petalSize, petalSize);
        g.fillOval(320 + x, 240, petalSize, petalSize);
        g.fillOval(290 + x, 240, petalSize, petalSize);
        g.fillOval(280 + x, 210, petalSize, petalSize);


        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);  //pistil(The middle thingy)
        g.fillOval(pistilPositionX + x, pistilPositionY, pistilSize, pistilSize);

        x = teller * 80;

        }

    }




    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        lblamount = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtamount = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        lblcolor = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtcolor = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        btngrow = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnreset = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnfertilize = new javax.swing.JButton();
        lblflower = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lblfarmer = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        lblamount.setText("Amount: ");

        txtamount.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txtamountActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        lblcolor.setText("Color: ");

        txtcolor.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txtcolorActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btngrow.setText("Grow!");
        btngrow.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btngrowActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnreset.setText("Reset Size");
        btnreset.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnresetActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnfertilize.setText("Fertilize");
        btnfertilize.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnfertilizeActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        lblflower.setText("FLOWER -->");

        lblfarmer.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Images/bird .gif"))); // NOI18N
        lblfarmer.setText("Bird");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(lblflower)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(lblamount)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(txtamount, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 57, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(lblcolor)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(txtcolor, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 59, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(btngrow)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(btnfertilize)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(btnreset)
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(lblfarmer, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 150, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(lblamount)
                    .addComponent(txtamount, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(lblcolor)
                    .addComponent(txtcolor, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btngrow)
                    .addComponent(btnreset)
                    .addComponent(btnfertilize)
                    .addComponent(lblflower))
                .addGap(78, 78, 78)
                .addComponent(lblfarmer)
                .addContainerGap(320, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void txtamountActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        amount = 1;
        txtamount.setText("" + amount); 
    }                                         

    private void txtcolorActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void btngrowActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    amount = Integer.parseInt(txtamount.getText());
    color = this.txtcolor.getText();
    repaint();

    }                                       

    private void btnfertilizeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
       if(fertilized == false){
            petalSize = (int) petalSize * 2;
            pistilSize = (int) pistilSize * 2;
            pistilPositionX += 8 ;
            pistilPositionY += 8 ;
            stemPositionX += 20;
            fertilized = true;
       repaint();
       }
    }                                            

    private void btnresetActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        petalSize = 40;
        pistilSize = 25;
        pistilPositionX -= 8 ;
        pistilPositionY -= 8 ;
        stemPositionX -= 20;
        fertilized = false;


        repaint();
    }                                        

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnfertilize;
    private javax.swing.JButton btngrow;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnreset;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblamount;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblcolor;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblflower;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtamount;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtcolor;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```